# Having problems installing in android plugins

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, android-install-apk, android-configchanges

```
I have installed eclipse .... and the package for linux intallation
```

I am using ubuntu

I have posted the pic below

[image]

If i need to install some package ... how to do it in ubuntu

**the error of missing requirement can be seen in the image**

Answer (score 1):

Try following below mentioned steps:-

1. Go to Help, "Install New Software."
2. Click on "Available Software Sites"
3. Search http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo and enable it(If using juno then just replace indigo with juno)
4. Come back to Help, "Install New Software."
5. Check "Contact all update sites during install to find required
   software"
6. Now follow the usual steps to install the ADT plugin, it should be able to automatically get the missing classes needed from the update site added above.

Hope this helps...